# Set selected default value of dropdown dynamically

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

How to change default selected value in DropDownList using Javascript?

I am new to JavaScript and i'm stuck at changing default selected value in dropdown list. 
Here i want to change my default selected value "111" to the new value. It has to change after i enter the text e.g."abc" into the Modal and when i hit the "Ok" button.Now it has to display default selected("abc")in to the dropdown list which i get from the text box of the modal. And also the old values has not changed in the list.

Code Snippet :

```
<form>
<select id="myList">
            <option>111</option>
            <option>222</option>
            <option>333</option>
        </select> <br>
        <br> 
</form>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <input type="text" id="addtext" size="50" /><br>
    Write & add text in the Dropdown list..</text>
    <br><br>
    <button id="okBtn">OK</button>

  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");


// Get the button that add text in the dropdown
var btn1 = document.getElementById("okBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

btn1.onclick = function(){
    //var element = document.getElementById('addtext');
    var y = document.getElementById("addtext");
    var x = document.getElementById("myList");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = y.value;
    x.add(option, option.defaultSelected, x[0] );



    modal.style.display = "none";

}



// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

I think i had done something wrong at

```
option.text = y.value;
    x.add(option, option.defaultSelected, x[0] );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property to set the index of the selected option.

If you set it to `0`, it will select the **first option**.

You can add an `option` to a `select` using [`HTMLSelectElement.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add). The correct syntax is (from the docs):

> ***collection.add(item[, before]);***
>
> *item* is an HTMLOptionElement or HTMLOptGroupElement
>
> *before* is optional
>   and  an element of the collection, or an index of type long,
>   representing the item item should be inserted before. If this
>   parameter is null (or the index does not exist), the new element is
>   appended to the end of the collection.

You were using **three** arguments, instead of **two**.

So, one possible approach is:

```
btn1.onclick = function(){
    /* ... */
    x.add(option, 0 ); //add as the first item, always
    x.selectedIndex = 0; //select the first item
    /* ... */

}
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/w1zqL0h9/

As said, if you pass `null` as a second argument, it will append your `option` to the end. And you can select it passing `length-1` to the `selectedIndex`.

```
btn1.onclick = function(){
    /* ... */
    x.add(option, null); //add option to the end
    x.selectedIndex = x.length-1; //select the last element
    /* ... */

}
```